# How to print a list as a string without parentheses

Tags: clojure, parentheses

I did:

```
user=> (println (for [line (range 1 5)] (str "line=" line)))
```

and got:

```
(line=1 line=2 line=3 line=4)
```

but I wanted only `line=1 line=2 line=3 line=4` as a string. How do I do this?

Comment: I solved my problem as follow - (eval (concat `(str) (for [line (range 1 5)] (str "line=" line))))

Answer (score 10):

You need 'apply'.

```
(apply println (for [line (range 1 5)] (str "line=" line)))
```

Alternatively,

```
(println (apply str (interpose " " (map #(str "line=" %) (range 1 5)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this one. `doseq` is about doing side-effect on sequences and printing is a side-effect.

```
(doseq [line (range 1 5) 
        :let [msg (str "line=" line " ")]] 
       (print msg))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `apply`, you could alternatively use [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) like so:

```
user> (reduce #(str %1 " line=" %2) "" (range 1 5))
=> " line=1 line=2 line=3 line=4"
```

The `reduce` function is a function that takes a function (let's call if **f**), a "starting value", and then a list of things that will be used as the second argument to **f**. It lazily calls **f** on the starting value and the first item in the list, then calls **f** on what this returns and the second item in the list, then calls **f** on what this returns and the third item in the list etc., until it has exhausted all the items in the list (or rather--since it's lazy, it will only go through the whole list if you "ask it to").

If you don't like starting space, you could wrap the whole thing in [`triml`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/triml) (you'd have to do `(use 'clojure.string)` first). Or you could do `(reduce #(str %1 "line=" %2 " ") (range 1 5))`, which would put the space at the end.

My experience has been that anytime you can do something with `apply`, you can do it slightly more elegantly with `reduce`. More importantly, my `reduce` alternative has <s>always</s> usually been faster than my `apply` one. <s>I certainly can't vouch that this will be true always, and I haven't done speed tests for your particular problem.</s>

**Edit**
I did some rough timings, using my version (`reduce`) versus JohnJ's second suggestion (`apply`), and found that they were pretty similar for up to `(range 1 100)`, but that by `(range 1 500)`, the `apply` version was at least 4x faster.

Comment: Reduce isn't really intended for iterating over a list for the purposes of calling code with side effects.